# Как я могу спарсить ссылку с этой страницы?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть страница сайта https://cq.ru/tournaments/dota-2. С нее мне нужно спарсить ссылку именно на тот турнир, по которому сейчас идет трансляция.

То есть если в
`<div class="tournament__meta"> Матч идет сейчас: <span>Cybercats vs YNT <span class="color-orange fwb">live</span> </span> </div>`

тег `<span class="color-orange fwb">live</span>` содержит в себе "live", то нужно взять атрибут href тегa `<a>`, который будет родителем именно этого тега `<span>`

Перепробовал всё подряд, ничего не могу сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = r'https://cq.ru/tournaments/dota-2'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
matches_live = soup.find_all("span", string="live")

for match in matches_live:
    info = match.find_parent('div', {'class': 'tournament__info'})
    info = info.find('div', {'class': 'tournament__middle'}).text.strip()
    link = match.find_parent('a')['href']
    print('{}\r\n{}\r\n'.format(info, link))
```

###### Вывод:

```console
Тир-2 Dota 2  2022 BTS Pro Series Season 13: Americas
https://cq.ru/tournaments/dota-2/2022-bts-pro-series-season-13-americas-bts-am

Тир-3 Dota 2  2022 Claro Gaming Apu League Season 5
https://cq.ru/tournaments/dota-2/2022-claro-gaming-apu-league-season-5-claro
```

[image: Скриншот в моменте]